# Unable to unmarshal xml-string to java object

Tags: java, xsd, namespaces

Unmarshal xml-string to java-object gives the following error:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"",
>   local:"AppServerResponse"). Expected elements are
>   <{http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver}AppServerResponse>

This is the AppServerResponse Java-class

```
@XmlRootElement (name = "AppServerResponse", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AppServerResponse", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver", propOrder = {
    "getEnvironment",
    "listUserCompanies",
    "softToHardDate"
})
public class AppServerResponse  extends ServiceResponse
{

    @XmlElement(name = "GetEnvironment", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver")

    protected GetEnvironmentResponseVerb getEnvironment;
    @XmlElement(name = "ListUserCompanies", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver")
    protected ListUserCompaniesResponseVerb listUserCompanies;
    @XmlElement(name = "SoftToHardDate", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver")

    protected SoftToHardDateResponseVerb softToHardDate;
```

The code for the unmarshal funtion and the xml-message been unmarshaled:

```
String strResponse = "<AppServerResponse uri=\"http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver\" version=\"2.0\" >"
                                + "<GetEnvironment>"
                                    + "<Response status=\"success\">"
                                        + "<Environment>"
                                            + "<CmpCode>TEST</CmpCode>"
                                            + "<CapCode>INTERFACE</CapCode>"
                                            + "<HomeCurr>EUR</HomeCurr>"
                                            + "<DateOrder>1</DateOrder>"
                                            + "<DateDisplay>1</DateDisplay>"
                                            + "<DateSep>/</DateSep>"
                                            + "<HomeCurrDps>2</HomeCurrDps>"
                                            + "<HomeCurrSymbol>€</HomeCurrSymbol>"
                                            + "<HomeCurrSymbolPos>before</HomeCurrSymbolPos>"
                                            + "<HomeCurrLinkType>no_link</HomeCurrLinkType>"
                                            + "<HomeCurrParent>EURO</HomeCurrParent>"
                                            + "<CurrentPeriod>2018/4</CurrentPeriod>"
                                            + "<CmpTimeStamp>11</CmpTimeStamp>"
                                            + "<CapTimeStamp>3</CapTimeStamp>"
                                            + "<UsrTimeStamp>12</UsrTimeStamp>"
                                            + "<ServerVersion>14.000.0014</ServerVersion>"
                                        + "</Environment>"
                                    + "</Response>"
                                + "</GetEnvironment>"
                            + "</AppServerResponse>";
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(false);
            DocumentBuilder db;

            db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document docResponse = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(strResponse)));

            writeXmlDocumentToXmlFile(docResponse);

            JAXBContext contextResponse = JAXBContext.newInstance(responseClass);
            Unmarshaller u = contextResponse.createUnmarshaller();

            returnValue = u.unmarshal(docResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JAXB annotations specify that your elements are in the `http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver` namespace, but the elements in your ressponse String are actually not in a namespace. It looks like you're intending to set the default namespace via

```java
String strResponse = "<AppServerResponse uri=\"http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver\"..."
```

But the `uri` attribute doesn't actually do that. Instead you need the `xmlns` attribute:

```java
String strResponse = "<AppServerResponse xmlns=\"http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver\"..."
```

Note the `xmlns` attribute name instead of `uri`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer .... I changed the response xml-string as follows, but it didn't help:>'''String strResponse = "<AppServerResponse xmlns:ns=\"http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver\" version=\"2.0\" >"'''                                                                                        I still get exactly the same exception. ... unexpected element (uri:"", local:"AppServerResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver}AppServerResponse>

Comment: Please note that the response is coming from an extern system and its not supposed to be changed in my code. I added here just for testing

Comment: In your comment you have ``xmlns:ns=``. The ``:ns`` is incorrect, since that associates the ``http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver`` namespace with the "ns" prefix. Your AppServerResponse does not have a prefix (e.g. <ns:AppServerResponse>) so is still not in that namespace. You instead need to have ``xmlns=``. If you are not supposed to change the strResponse but can change your JAXB code, you might try removing all the ``namespace = ...`` in the @XmlElement annotations.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. We did try this option too (xmlns="" ...). The result was exactly the same (didn't solve the problem).

Comment: Removing the namespaces in Java-class didn't help either.

Comment: Changing java-class: @XmlRootElement (name = "AppServerResponse", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AppServerResponse", namespace = "http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver", propOrder = {
    "getEnvironment",
    "listUserCompanies",
    "softToHardDate"
})                                         
Error message: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"AppServerResponse"). Expected elements are <{http://www.coda.com/efinance/schemas/appserver}AppServerResponse>